# Getting 'column must be greater than or equal to 0' error while trying to extract locales using 'ng extract-i18n' with Angular Calendar

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-calendar

I currently have the problem that I am unable to extract my locales with the following command `ng extract-i18n --output-path src/locale` . I am getting this error while using the command:

```
./node_modules/angular-calendar/fesm2020/angular-calendar.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
Error: /node_modules/angular-calendar/fesm2020/angular-calendar.mjs: `column` must be greater than or equal to 0 (columns start
```

I don't know why Angular calendar is a problem for the extraction of my locales.

I tried:

- Reinstalling angular calendar
- deleting the package-log.json and running npm install afterwards

Comment: Related ticket on the angular-calendar project: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/issues/1671